# Enable input field based on another input drop down field selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having a form as:

```
<%= form_for(@employee , html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role,"Role", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls"></div>
    <%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.all, :id, :role_name, prompt: "-- Select --") %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :is_sales_report_visible," Visible Factory Sales", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls"></div>
    <%= f.check_box :is_sales_report_visible, {}, true, false %>
    <div class="field"></div>
    <%= f.label :is_invoice_visible," Visible Invoice Details", :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls"></div>
    <%= f.check_box :is_invoice_visible,input_html: { :class => 'check_box' } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions1">
    <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-md' %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", employees_path(), :class => 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to cancel' } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There are 2 roles: admin and user in my application which will be visible in drop down.
My requirement is, the check box field should be default hidden and when I select role as "user", this check boxes has to be visible.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  class to your main div of check boxes as:

```
<div class="field user_checkbox_fields" style="display:none;">
```

Add this to your java script file or html file, it may work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#employee_role_id").click(function () {
        if($("#employee_role_id")[0].value=="User") {
            $(".user_checkbox_fields").css("display","block");           
        }
        else {
            $(".user_checkbox_fields").css("display","none");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one class into the select box for Role like,

```
<%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.all, :id, :role_name, prompt: "-- Select --",{:class=>'role'}) %>
```

Add one more class to your main div of checkboxes and change to,

```
<div class="field user_checkbox_fields" style="display:none;">
```

And add javascript code like,

```
$('.role').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "user") {
    $('.user_checkbox_fields').show();
  }
  else{
    $('.user_checkbox_fields').hide();
  }
});
$('.role').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No action taking place. When i gave class name as role and check with firebug, it is not shown. So I've tried with  "#employee_role_id"(id) in place of class, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from markup (or at least some classes names), I assume you use bootstrap, am I right? So you can take benefit of existing stuff, like `hidden` class. If not, you can always define it in css:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

I understand the generated select has id `employee_role_id`, so it could be done like this. It's a slightly adjusted version of @rick's solution.

Add classes a selector to checkbox wrapping div. `checkboxes` to identify the wrapper, `hidden` to hide it initially.

```
<div class="field checkboxes hidden">
// your checkboxes here...
</div>
```

And then some scripting:

```
$(document).on("change", "select[id$='role_id']", function() {
  # toggleClass applies or removes a class from DOM element
  # depending on boolean value of the second argument
  $(".checkboxes").toggleClass("hidden", $(this).val() != "user")
});

$("select[id$='role_id']").trigger("change");
```

I find it better to use class to indicate if something is hidden or not. It's easier to perform, for example, automated tests.

However if you'd like to avoid using this additional `hidden` class, you can of course go with `display: none;` directly in the markup, like @rick posted. With script looking like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "select[id$='role_id']", function() {
  # toggle shows or hides DOM element
  # depending on boolean value of the second argument
  $(".checkboxes").toggle($(this).val() != "user")
});

$("select[id$='role_id']").trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks Krzysztof Rygielski, it's working with `$(document).on("change", "select[id$='role_id']", function() {
  # toggleClass applies or removes a class from DOM element
  # depending on boolean value of the second argument
  $(".checkboxes").toggleClass("hidden", $().val() == "user")
});

$("select[id$='role_id']").trigger("change");` . but when I select  admin or Selet is selected, the check boxes has to hide.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed out something. I've updated the example so that checkboxes are visible on user role and hidden otherwise (not the other way around - as I've misunderstood it).